# UINavigationController NavigationBar not applying transparent image

Tags: swift, xcode

When applying transparent image in the navigation tab bar. It's turning white instead of being transparent..

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that something is under the navigation bar so that it does not just become transparent showing the white background. You will need to drag uiviews under it and then add layout constraints. Otherwise, make sure you check that you have not changed the color of the navigation bar elsewhere.

Comment: Yes there is something beneath the navigation bar, since when i try to drag to it bottom half of the image content it still there.. so definitely the navigation bar is white.

"Otherwise, make sure you check that you have not changed the color of the navigation bar elsewhere." 
- Yes i'm still checking if there is something that triggers it elsewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to make navigation bar transperant.

```swift
extension UINavigationController {
    func transparant() {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Navigation Controller try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
title = "Some Title"
```

if you are using UINavigationBar try this:

```
@IBOutlet var navBarOutlet: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // navigatin bar transparent
        navBarOutlet.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for:.default)
        navBarOutlet.shadowImage=UIImage()
        navBarOutlet.topItem?.title = "Some Title"

}
```